# Get time only in string ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm crawling data from website. And this is string I received when I parse Html by Nokogiri

```
"0:10\r\n              (+1)\r\n            "
"03:10\r\n              (+1)\r\n            "
```

How can I get only "0:10" and "03:10" ?

**UPDATE**

And what's different between `match` and `gsub` ?

Thanks !

Comment: /\d{0,2}:\d{0,2}/.match("0:10\r\n              (+1)\r\n            ")

if you want to make it even smarter, you can use this regex:

([0-1]?[0-9]+|[2][0-4]):[0-5][0-9]

Comment: You would use gsub when you want to replace. Match just matches

Comment: Exactly, gsub will return the string with _all_ matches replaced by a string you supply. Match will just return the text of the _first_ match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shoud use the regex `/\d{0,2}:\d{0,2}/` @engineer14 posted. It works, here's proof:

```js
console.log("0:10\r\n              (+1)\r\n            ".match(/\d{0,2}:\d{0,2}/)[0])
console.log("03:10\r\n              (+1)\r\n            ".match(/\d{0,2}:\d{0,2}/)[0])
```

Explanation:

```
/ <-- open regex
\d <-- look for digit
{0,2} <-- zero or more of them
: <-- look for a colon
\d <-- look for another digit
{0,2} <-- zero or more of them
/ <-- close regex
```

Comment: You might want to give him a quick explanation.

Comment: You might want to take credit for this answer, I'm not sure why you just left a comment, as oppose to an answer. Post an answer if you want and I'll delete this one.

Comment: Agree with @mar, but your explanation is also good for me ! Thanks all !

Comment: Your regex matches many unrelated strings. For example, `"The answer: work smarter".match(/\d{0,2}:\d{0,2}/)[0 => ":"`.

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression should only match strings that have the required pattern.

```
r = /
    \A                    # match beginning of string
    (                     # begin capture group 1
      \d+                 # match one or more digits
      :                   # match a colon
      \d{2}               # match two digits
    )                     # end capture group 1
    \r\n\s+\(\+1\)\r\n\s+ # match substring
    \z                    # match end of string
    /x                    # free spacing regex definition mode

"0:10\r\n              (+1)\r\n            "[r,1]
  #=> "0:10" 
"03:10\r\n              (+1)\r\n            "[r,1]
  #=> "03:10" 
"0:101\r\n              (+1)\r\n            "[r,1]
  #=> nil 
":10\r\n              (+1)\r\n            "[r,1]
  #=> nil 
"0:10 \r\n              (+1)\r\n            "[r,1]
  #=> nil 
"0:10\r\n              (+2)\r\n            "[r,1]
  #=> nil 
"0:10\r\n              (+1)\r\n         cat"[r,1]
  #=> nil
```

Depending on how the string may vary, some changes may be necessary to your pattern. For example, If "+1" in parentheses might be "+" followed by any positive number, you would need to replace `\(\+1\)` with `\(\+\d+\)`.

Answer (score 0):

what site are you crawling? the +1 might be important to consider if it is a timezone.

Comment: That's not problem bro. I ignore it :)

Comment: This should be a comment.